# Report with calling form

Tags: civireport, forms, reports

A user handed me a printed sheet from a previous database and asked me to recreate it. It contains contact information, a list of contributions, the most recent memo, and several blanks to be filled in during a renewal call (call response, pledged donation, written notes, some checkboxes, etc.). And it must be printed as a hard copy.

So I think what I'm looking for is a way to combine report data and fill-in-the-blank fields in one sheet. The "Constituent Detail" report works well for the former, but I'm stumped on getting the latter included on the same page. Anyone have a clever suggestion?

Comment: If you are in Drupal then Views may do what you want (but pasting a screenshot of this form you need would make advising easier) and kind of depends whether you are printing one sheet per call, or just a whole big table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Administer > Communications > Message Templates
Add New Message Template
Give your message a title
Insert the tokens needed to get the donor info needed. 
Add the bottom fillable response card.

Here is a very helpful posting about this https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/blob/master/docs/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous.md

Comment: This was the best solution. Thank you. There were some elements of reports I wished I could include (list of contributions) but by using the Summary Fields extension there was enough contribution info to make the client happy.

Comment: You can list contributions using foreach. Do something like:

Comment: {foreach from=$contributions item=contribution} {assign
    var="date" value=$contribution.receive_date|date_format:"%B %d %Y"}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='LineItem' action='get' contribution_id=$contribution.id} 
  {foreach from=$result.values item=lineitem} 
    
  -->

Comment: <tr style="padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #281c1d;">
   <td style="padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #281c1d;">{$date}</td>
   <td style="padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #281c1d;">{$contribution.id}</td>
   <td style="padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #281c1d;">{$lineitem.label}</td>
   <td style="text-align:right;padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #281c1d;">$ {$lineitem.line_total}</td>
  </tr>
  <!--
    {/foreach}{/foreach}

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of allowed space for comments so I had to break it up